# RFM69HCW connected to Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, lora

I have a prototype LoRa Daughter Board that utilizes RFM69HCW transceiver module. I found an interesting blog online that covers everything courtesy of Sparkfun. Here's the link [RFM69HCW Tutorial by Sparkfun 2.](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/rfm69hcw-hookup-guide/all)

I followed everything but the 2 RFM69HCW radios that I am working on didn't communicate to each other. When I checked my prototype board, DI0 of the RFM69HCW has no connection at all. Is it necessary to connect the DI0 to hardware interrupt pin of Arduino Uno? And also, can I connect it directly to the Arduino board if ever? Thanks in advance for whoever will shed light on this one.

Comment: You're saying the DIO0 pad on your breakout board doesn't connect internally to the LoRa module mounted on it?

Comment: unfortunately, yes @Majenko basically the DI0 pin in my prototype board is with no connection. Was it the reason why the RFM69HCW transceiver modules didn't communicating to each other?